# Can´t work out the "Range.Find" the Next Cell on a Userform Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This code brings from a column, the first data that is inserted. But i want to show the one before, which would be the next cell. How i can do that? I tried with different Range.Find methods but is not working. I tried the old trick of the `FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Value - 1` but it did not work, just to fool around i guess...

```
  Set FindRow = Hoja6.Range("B:B").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

  'sort the Registros by "Último Ingreso"
  Hoja6.Select
  With LogsUsuarios
      .Range("C4:C1000").Sort Key1:=Range("C4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
  End With

  If cRow = "RESCARIZ" Then
  Me.UserLog.Text = FindRow
  Me.LastUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End If
```

Here is the column im working with

[image]

Comment: "But i want to show the one before, which would be the next cell" - that is very unclear, please explain.

Comment: Try `Offset(0, -1).Value` if you want the value of the previous cell on a row. or `Offset(-1, 0).Value` to obtain the value of the previous cell on a column...

Comment: It will show the last time they logged in. So when they login, the first cell, after it reorders, it will appear as the time they just logged, but i want to show the cell before that, that contains the last time they logged, not today, but yesterday for example, if its the case for this example. Hope this is a little more clear.

Comment: Not really lol, but maybe @FaneDuru has better cognitive abilities.

Comment: Not really... Try to better specify **where that first cell** appears? Do you need the previous cell on a row, or on a column? I made some suggestions from this point of view...

Comment: @FaneDuru i tried that, but neither work. If i use the Offset(0, -1) it will bring a blank cell, which its the one before the username cell. And if i use the other one, it brings the title name

Comment: @SJR: I only supposed that his problem is the last code row, before `End If`. Taking in consideration his words explanation regarding Offset 'definition'... :)

Comment: OK. Give us an example: The new input key is B3 and I need to return what? B2 or A2? Or what, if any supposition doesn't match?

Comment: To make it with an Example: I have Cell A and B. That cells when the user log, it will be filled with their user and records the time they enter the system. I want to show the last time they did enter, so it should be the cell below the one just created.

Comment: Since words don't seem to be helping, how about posting a picture?

Comment: If i have B2 as the new cell, i need B1 to show

Comment: Then, how `Offset(-1, 0)` didn't help?

Comment: I added a pic to make it more clearer. (-1, 0) did not work

Comment: Use `.Offset(-1,1)`

Comment: My last value its the 14:14 but i want to show the 13:48. So that would be the time "they last logged"

Comment: But, you said that you need B2, for B1 like new cell...

Comment: I don't think we've tried `Offset(1,1)` yet.

Comment: (1,1) seems working. Need to test it a couple of times to see it does work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it's pretty clear that you have not explained the cell that you want very clearly. Instead of giving the exact Offset, use this chart to determine where you need to go.

The green cell indicates your found cell. The associated offsets are assigned to the surrounding cells

[image]

---

You would probably benefit from also taking a look at the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) around `Offset`

Comment: Actually didn´t thought of making a mini table to check each value where they where going, i did it quickly just testing, but was not the best solution. Sorry if i did not make it clearer at start and thanks for sharing.

Comment: From looking at the comments it sounds like `Offset(1, 1)` is what you may have wanted. This will go over one column to right and down one cell as shown in diagram. This solution was aimed at you being able to self-serve the answer.

Comment: That chart tho :-)